# Get number of count of a value in database table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, database

Good day. I am building an API, in which I want to return some data. I have three tables

1. counsels
2. counsel_cases
3. analysis_sc

**A section of the counsels table is shown below**

[image]

**A section of the counsel_cases is also shown below**

[image]

**Finally, a section of the analysic_sc is shown below.**

[image]

I want that when a counsel is selected, through the counsel_id, I can fetch the cases belonging to the counsel from the counsel_cases, and then with that information, I want to be able to fetch the number of cases of such a counsel belonging to a legal head (area of practice) on the third table as shown in the design below.

[image]

How will that be possible. I have a relationship between counsel and counsel_cases though. Also, I have tried using a foreach loop as shown below, but I am unable to get the unique values of the legal_head.

```
    public function getCounselPracticeAreas(Request $request)
    {
        $counsel_id = $request->route('counsel_id');
        $cases = CounselCase::select('suit_number')->where('counsel_id', $counsel_id)->get();

        $data = [];
        foreach ($cases as $case) {
            $values = AnalysisSc::select('legal_head')->where('suitno', $case->suit_number)->first(); 
            array_push($data, $values);
        }

        return response()->json([
            "message" => "successful",
            "data" => $data
        ]);
    }
However, this is the value I get
[![enter image description here][5]][5]
```

I want to get something like this:

```
$data : [
            "legal_head" : [
                "name" : "Criminal Law",
                "count" : 2
             ]   
       ]
```

Please, is this possible
I know this is quite long. And I hope I explained myself well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to use SQL Joins to create a relationship between the tables and fetch the data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're skipping using relationships in your models. Once you have your models set up, retrieving the data you need will be a lot easier with Laravel. You may want to separate your models/tables a little more and add relationships, like the following:

## Models/tables:

**Counsel** (counsels)

> - id
> - name

**LegalHead** (legal_heads)

> - id
> - name

**Case** (cases)

> - id
> - suit_number
> - year
> - subject_matter
> - legal_head_id

case_counsels (*This is not a model, just a relationship table*)

> - id
> - case_id
> - counsel_id
> - appearing_for
> - role

*Note: I wasn't sure how your data is structured. You can use this as start and adjust as necessary.*

## Relationships

The Many-Many relationship is suitable for the case counsels and you'll be able to add the role as a pivot(extra field) for the relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

**Case**

- legal_head: belongsTo
- counsels: belongsToMany with pivot for role

**Counsel**

- cases: belongsToMany with pivot for role

## Retrieving the Objects

When that is set up, you won't have to do as much query work. You can do this to get case data with **counsels**, **legal_head** and their role for each case:

```
$cases = Case::with('counsels','legal_head')->get();
```

And this to get the Legal Head names with the number of cases:

```
$legal_heads = LegalHead::withCount('cases')->get();
```